# Markdown and email

Tags: applications, email, text-layout

Do you know of a way to add hyperlinks, use italics or bold faces, add mathematical formulæ and do all this kind of fancy stuff to write an email on an Android phone?

I know there are apps such as [MarkdownX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryeeeeee.markdownx) that let you write *documents* with all those proprieties or export them in various formats but this is not what I'm looking for: I'd like to write an email just as I'm doing now while writing this question, without attaching any file.

Yes, I know that I could just connect with a PC and write the message using [some web browser extensions](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/markdown-here/&ved=0ahUKEwig7veOyOzKAhXFChoKHTE2AaoQFggkMAE&usg=AFQjCNHJKcoC7Houw-UDZttPgScsbA9xJw&sig2=lj_To0l01hJMQToCbQzwZQ), but I'd like to do all the work using my phone.

Answer (score 0):

As for the text editing part, [Gmail's new update](http://drippler.com/drip/you-can-now-bold-italicize-underline-text-gmail-app) (February 24th, 2016) has partially provided a solution: it is now possible to give the desired emphasis to your own email adding bold, italic, underlined, coloured or highlighted words *just using [Gmail for mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm)*.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]